# src attribute of img tag inside div with a known id?

Tags: regex

Inside a string that contains an html document that looks like :

```
<html>
  ... stuff ...

  <div class="container">
    <p><strong>Message title</strong></p>
    <textarea class="txtarea" id="txtarea">
      <table cellpadding="2">
        <a href="http://somewhere.com"> 
          <img src="http://mycdn.com/mypicId.jpg" width="280" height="280"> 
        </a> 
      </table>
    </textarea>
  </div>

  ... stuff ...
</html>
```

, **using regex**, how do I get the src attribute of the img tag inside the div with class "container", knowing that there are multiple other img tags in other parts of the html ?

Comment: Known id or known class name? :)

Comment: See my [update](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9664423/601179), **Your markup isn't valid**, as you have `<img>` inside `<textarea>` **?!**

Answer (score 1):

No need to regex, use jQuery

```
var src = $('.container img').eq().attr('src')
```

[eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) allows to to specify which single element to return.

You could also use [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) in the selector

Comment: no javascript, no jquery, just regex. Sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: so the chunk is a string, being passed into regex?

Comment: Yes, it is a string.  Sorry the original question was misleading in that regard.  Just modified it.

Answer (score 1):

**Plain Javascript:**

```
var src = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0]
                  .getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
```

**jQuery:**

```
var src = $('.container img').attr('src');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbgTr/)

---

By the way, **That HTML isn't valid** as you have `<img>` inside `<textarea>` **?!**

Comment: no javascript, no jquery, just regex. Sorry if it was not clear.